# T-SQL (SQL Server 2016) trigger for column value alter, at Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am working on a SSIS project of mine. I have successfully manage to load some csv's into my database (through Integration Services in VS) and now I am trying to create a trigger in the database.

All I want to happen is: when the number of the column `second_road_class` is -1 I want it to change into 6. I want the trigger to fire during the inserts.

My trigger code seems to debug ok in SSMS! But when I am later trying to insert the csv's again, the `second_road_class` column with `-1` stays as it is.

Trigger code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER AccidentsTrigger
ON [Accidents]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF (SELECT [second_road_class] FROM INSERTED) LIKE '-1'
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [Accidents]
        SET [second_road_class] = '6'
        WHERE [second_road_class] = '-1'
    END
END
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This doesn't work - `INSTEAD OF` really means `INSTEAD OF` - there is no row to update because the trigger fires first (and no row will ever be inserted unless you insert the row yourself in the trigger). "It compiled!" or "It didn't make the debugger barf" ~= working as intended.

Comment: I really tried plenty workarounds. Now i am working on the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with an `after insert` trigger.

```
create trigger accidentstrigger on [accidents]
after insert as 
begin;
    set nocount on;
    if exists (select 1 from inserted where [second_road_class] = '-1')
    begin;
        update a 
        set [second_road_class] = '6'
        from [accidents] as a
          inner join inserted i 
          /* change AccidentId to the Primary Key on accidents*/
            on a.AccidentId = i.AccidentId 
           and i.[second_road_class] = '-1';
    end;
end;
go
```

Example using the `pilots` table on rextester: http://rextester.com/XKX10184

Comment: Still nothing. Is there a problem that i am loading the CSV into the DB from VS IS with a data flow?

Comment: Seems there has to be done some adjustments in the package settings. Now it works. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Apparently there is still something i can't deal with. The trigger is returning the following error for multiple rows(but works fine for single row Insert)
`Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Comment: @MrDiaman I don't think that error is from the trigger above, as there is no subquery returning any value. Check the insert statement or for other triggers that use a subquery that could return multiple values.